# Reducing data in data frame to plot data in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm very new to programming so I apologise in advance for my lack of R know-how. I'm a PhD student interested in pupillometry and I have just recorded the pupil response of participants performing a listening task in two conditions (Easy and Hard). The pupil response interest period for each trial is around 20 seconds and I would like to be able to plot this data for each participant on R. The eyetracker sampling rate is 1000Hz and each participant completed 92 trials. So the data that I currently have for each participant includes close to 2million rows. I have tried to plot this using ggplot2 but, as expected, the graph is very cluttered.

I've been trying to work out a way of reducing the data so that I can plot it on R. Ideally, I would like to take the mean pupil size value for every 1000 samples (i.e. 1 second of recording) averaged across all 92 trials for each participant. With this information, I would then create a new dataframe for plotting the average slope from 1-20 seconds for the two listening conditions (Easy and Hard).

Here is the current structure of my data frame;

```
> str(ppt53data)
'data.frame':   1915391 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL: Factor w/ 1 level "ppt53": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ listening_condition    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Easy","Hard": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE       : Factor w/ 3690 levels ".","0.00","1000.00",..: 3266 3264 3263 3262 3262 3260 3257 3254 3252 3252 ...
 $ TIMESTAMP              : num  262587 262588 262589 262590 262591 ...
 $ TRIAL_START_TIME       : int  262587 262587 262587 262587 262587 262587 262587 262587 262587 262587 ...
 $ TrialTime              : num  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:278344] 873 874 875 876 877 878 879 880 881 882 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:278344] "873" "874" "875" "876" ...
```

The 'TrialTime' variable specifies the sample (i.e. millisecond) in each trial. Can anyone advise me about which step I should take next? I figure it would make sense to arrange my data into separate data frames which would allow me to calculate the mean values that I want (across trials and for every 1000 samples). However, I'm not sure what is the most efficient/best way of doing this.

I'm sorry that I can't be any more specific. Any rough guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: IMHO it would be better if you posted your data somewhere that we could get at it (Dropbox?). Or at least a representative subset.

Comment: FYI: RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE has non-numeric data in it - you can get rid of this by setting them up as `na.strings` in your import. `read.csv("myfile.csv",na.strings=".")`

Comment: Brandon, thanks for pointing that out - I've just changed that variable so that it's only numeric data. JLHoward, thanks for your comment - I will try to post my data if I have any more queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for such a large block of data with many aggregation levels you will need to use `data.table`. I may have mis-structured your data, but hopefully this will give you the idea:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

#100 patient * 20,000 observations (1-20,000 ms)
ppt53data<-data.frame(
  RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL=paste0("pat-",rep(1:100,each=20000)),    #patients
  listening_condition=sample(c("Easy","Hard"),2000000,replace=T),  #Easy/Hard
  RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE=rnorm(2000000,3000,500),                        #Pupil Size
  TrialTime=rep(1:20000,100)                                       #ms from start
)

# group in 1000ms blocks
ppt53data$group<-cut(ppt53data$TrialTime,c(0,seq(1000,20000,1000),Inf))

unique(ppt53data$group)

#convert frame to table
dt.ppt53data<-data.table(ppt53data)

#index
setkey(dt.ppt53data, RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL, group)

#create data.frame of aggregated plot data
plot.data<-data.frame(dt.ppt53data[,list(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE=mean(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE)),by=list(group)])

#plot with ggplot2
ggplot(plot.data)+geom_bar(aes(group,RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE,stat="identity",fill=group)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(2995,3005))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this example. The one problem I'm having though is trying to summarise each second (every 1000 miliseconds). I think the way you have demonstrated this here (understandably) assumes that there is exactly 20000 rows for each patient.  Unfortunately though, the rows/samples are a different length for each patient. So, what I would like to do is add a variable which describes which second each sample applies to (e.g. 1:20) based on this kind of labelling; 1:1000 = 1, 1001:2000 = 2, 2001:3000 = 3, and so on until the samples end. Can you think of a way of doing this?

Comment: @Ronan Sure - one quick change to the `cut()` call, which I will make above - 'ppt53data$group<-cut(ppt53data$TrialTime,c(0,seq(1000,20000,1000),Inf))'

Answer (score 0):

Some rough guidance:

```
library(plyr)

ppt53data.summarized <- ddply(ppt53data, .(TrialTime), summarize, mean = mean(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE))
```

This tells it to calculate the mean size of the right pupil for each unique TrialTime. Perhaps seeing how this works would help you figure out how to describe what you need?

Assuming that within each TrailTime there are more than 1000 observations, you can randomly select:

```
set.seed(42)
ppt53data.summarized <- ddply(ppt53data, .(TrialTime), summarize, mean = mean(sample(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE,1000)))
```

Comment: This code proved very useful as it performed one of the tasks I was aiming to do (average pupil size for each second across every trial). I was hoping to be able to use a similar code to find averages for every 1000 samples. Using the ddply() function, is there any way to apply the mean function to every 1000 samples in the data rather than doing it for every unique value (as in the code you provided)?

Comment: I'll update the answer with an example that shows you how to take a random sample of 1000.